# How to print one line from ArrayList based on a textfile?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, text-files

Right now we can print out one line from out from a textfile by
 pressing the line number.  Problem is when we are able to print out a 
 line number again (products), until we reach the limit of products in 
 our textfile.  How can we stop the loop so it only print the one line 
 we choose?

```
static ArrayList<Product> printOneLine() {
    ArrayList<Product> oneLineList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Scanner oneLine = readDetails("Products-JavaBikes.txt");

    while (oneLine.hasNextLine()) {
        oneLineList.add(getProduct(oneLine.nextLine()));

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);            
        System.out.print("Please enter a number:");

        for (int i = input.nextInt(); i < oneLineList.size();) {                    
            System.out.println(oneLineList.get(i));
            break;
        }   
    }
    return oneLineList;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you ask the number inside the line iteration loop instead of asking it just once in the beginning and then using the result for finding the correct line?

Comment: You should get the number from the user interface and then you can just return oneList.get(userEnteredLineNumber);

Comment: That for-loop makes no sense, I imagine you're looking for an if-statement instead. For loops are for looping, if you break unconditionally in the first iteration, you're doing something very wrong. Also, you may want to debug your code or even just think through what it's doing, step by step - it doesn't help you in the long term for us to just tell you how to fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear from your question. But I think you're trying to break from your while loop on finding the product entered. I changed the redundant for loop to an if statement, so that you can break from the while loop. Your break is just breaking from the for loop, not the while loop.

```
static ArrayList<Product> printOneLine() {
    ArrayList<Product> oneLineList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    Scanner oneLine = readDetails("Products-JavaBikes.txt");

    while (oneLine.hasNextLine()) {
        oneLineList.add(getProduct(oneLine.nextLine()));

        System.out.print("Please enter a number:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);            

        if(input.nextInt() < oneLineList.size()) {                    
            System.out.println(oneLineList.get(i));
            break;
        }   
    }
    return oneLineList;
}
```